# Facebook Graph API :: /<user_id>/posts :: Endpoint not returning data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I started to have an issues getting data from Facebook Graph API under the edge posts of the user object:

These 2, return an empty data array:

https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/<user_id>/posts
or
https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/me/posts

But,
https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/me/feed
or
https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/<user_id>/feed

return the correct data.

As per FB documentation at
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v8.0/user/feed

> /{user-id}/feed
>
> The feed of posts (including status updates) and links published by
> this person, or by others on this person's profile. There are other
> edges which provide filtered versions of this edge:
>
> /{user-id}/posts shows only the posts that were published by this
> person.
>
> /{user-id}/tagged shows only the posts that this person was
> tagged in.

Anyone facing the same issue?
I'll open an ticket near Facebook and I'll share the details here.

Cheers

Comment: FB Ticket: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/605449726803761/

Comment: It was solved by the FB team.

Comment: While the API endpoint was "down", I've used the /{user-id}/feed or /me/feed endpoint to get the same data. Watch out for the from object to match the user posts.